# Who is the crying person Butterfly thinks of in the 32nd enigma?

Tags: phantom-tales-of-the-night

In the 32nd enigma of Phantom Tales of the Night, there's a scene where a doll seller suggests to Butterfly that perhaps people that can't stand change are monsters. Afterwards, Butterfly pictures the face of a crying person before going on to destroy several dolls.

Who is this crying person that Butterfly pictures? How do they relate to what the doll seller said?

[image: butterfly thinks of a crying person]